# Is $f(x)=(x-1)\sin (1/(x-1))$ differentiable at $x=0$ is $f(0)=\sin1!$

Tags: limits, derivatives

The answer is No.

But I think it should be differentiable as I am getting
$$\text{Left hand derivative}=\text{Right hand derivative}$$
at $x=0$.

Please give with proof using first principles.

Comment: Hi user. Can you please show us the things you are "getting", specifically? Click "Edit" above. If you haven't tried anything, this question perhaps doesn't belong here. Also we suggest you review this material: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is wrong: the function is differentiable at $x=0$. It's just not differentiable in $x=1$.

The derivative is, for $x\neq1$:

$$ \dfrac{df}{dx} = \sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x-1}\right) - \dfrac{1}{x-1} \cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x-1}\right), $$ which leads you to $ f'(0) = \cos(1) - \sin(1) $.

Comment: But you have differentiated without proving differentiabily and differentiation is wrong

Comment: I showed you that it has derivative in zero, your original question said not. You can prove it using the definition. You could try showing it by definition (using limits) and then if you have any questions, ask me here :)

Comment: I also got the same answer but this is an AIEEE problem with answer as No and I don't think the answer will be wrong

Comment: @user871173, one difficulty with your question is its ungrammatical use of two "is"s, which makes it impossible to figure out what's actually being asked. It's a bit like saying "Is the apple red is edible." One can *guess* at the meaning, but it's hard to be sure. (For one thing, there's no question mark!) I would recommend going back to where the problem came from and stating it here *exactly* as it appears there.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is differentiable at $x=0$. The only point where the function is NOT differentiable (although is continuous) is $x=1$.

Comment: Can you write a proof

Comment: Do you not understand?  If one can calculate the derivatrive, then that proves it is differentiable!